# Prove that if p is a prime, then each element of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a root of $x^p-x$.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, roots

Question is given in the title. I have tried picking an arbitrary element $\overline{a}$ and then using the division algorithm to try to show that my remainder is zero when dividing $x^p-x$ with $x-\overline{a}$. This gives me a remainder of $(\overline{a}^{p-1}-1)x$. How do I see that this is zero? I feel blind to it, yet I feel like my method so far is correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know Fermat's (little) Theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem

Comment: Use Lagrange's theorem to show that for each element $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, you have $a^{p-1}-1=0$ whence $a^p=a$. Now the last element for which the relation might not hold is $a=0$ (the only non-invertible element mod $p$) for which $a^p=a$ is obviously true.

Comment: Write $a$ as a sum $1+1+\cdots+1$ ($a$ times) and use the binomial theorem.

Comment: So basically the answer to my question is the proof of Fermat's little theorem? My luck haha

Answer (score 2):

The statement follow by Fermat's theorem. Let $[a]\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ then we have

$$a^p \equiv a \text{ (mod } p);$$

equivalently $$ a^p-a\equiv 0 \text{ (mod } p).$$

So every elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of the polynomial $q(x)=x^p-x$. Moreover in this field $q(x)$ can be decompose in simple factors

$$q(x)=x(x-[a_1])...(x-[a_{p-1}])$$
 in unique way.